# Java Spring MVC get/post in same JSP

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

this is from my controller..

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String add(Model model) {
    return "add";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String added(@RequestParam("name") String name, Model model) {
    City city = new City();
    city.setCity(name);
    service.addCity(city);
    return "add";
}
```

this is my JSP view..this is only for adding at the moment...this is add.jsp..so it posts back to itself

```
    <form method="post" action="/spring/krams/edit/add">
Linna nimi
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit" value="Test" name="submit" />
</form>
```

i would like the JSP file change , so that when i post it to this file, then it says..."CITY ADDED" . is that possible?

WHAT ABOUT UPDATING A CITY??

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updated(@RequestParam("city") int city_id,
                      @RequestParam("text") String name,
                      Model model) {
    service.updateCity(name, city_id);
    return "update";
}
```

Here is no object?

Comment: What do you mean JSP file change? Do you just want to show a text message "city added" in add.jsp?

Comment: @CoolBeans : yes, after i have pressed the button and it added to database, i want it to show City Added

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the post method you can add an attribute with addAttribute method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String added(@RequestParam("name") String name, Model model) {
    City city = new City();
    city.setCity(name);
    service.addCity(city);
    model.addAttribute("city", city);
    return "add";
}
```

and in the JSP you can check if the attribute city is null or not (with the tag `<c:if/>`). In case it is not null, it is because it has just been added to the model, so you can show whatever you want. `${city.city}` its just a JSTL expression which accesses to the city attribute and then call the getter to access to the city property of that attribute:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" prefix="c" %>

<c:if test="${city != null}">
    CITY <c:out value="${city.city}" /> ADDED
</c:if>
```

**UPDATE**

If you need different messages depending on update/create operations you can do this: (In the example an update is done when the id param is not null because the id is the identifier of the city to update)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String added(@RequestParam(value="id", required=false) String id, @RequestParam("name") String name, Model model) {
    City city;
    String operation;
    if(id== null){
        //create operation
        city = new City();
        operation = "CREATE";

    }else{
        //update operation
        city = service.findCity(id);
        operation = "UPDATE";
    }
    city.setCity(name);        
    service.saveCity(city); //save or update
    model.addAttribute("city", city);
    model.addAttribute("operation", operation); //add operation param
    return "add";
}
```

and in the JSP you can do:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" prefix="c" %>

<c:if test="${operation == 'CREATE'}">
    <c:if test="${city != null}">
          CITY <c:out value="${city.city}" /> ADDED
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${operation == 'UPDATE'}">
          CITY <c:out value="${city.city}" /> UPDATED
    </c:if>
</c:if>
```

Comment: thanks, it worked..what if i want to say UPDATED?.. look my controller on main post

Comment: @Jaanus You can say whatever you want. If there are different cases (create, update...) you'll need a way to see in the jsp which operation is the one happening. You can add another attribute in the controller for example called operation and in the c:if tag do something like test="${operation == 'UPDATE'}"

Comment: can you add that exmaple to your post , how to add another attirbute to controller ?

Comment: @Jaanus example added. You can add as many attributes as you want. You only need to call addAttribute again.